# How can I prove if l1 is as twice as steep as l2?

Tags: slope

[image]

How do I find the slope of each line using SohCahToa? I plan on using the unit circle but I am having difficulty calculating slope.

Comment: The slope is just arctan of the angle, if that's what's your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The slope is tangent of the angle made with the positive direction of the x-axis.

Thus you have $$ m_1 = \tan (\pi/6) \approx .5777$$ and $$ m_2 = \tan (\pi/3) \approx 1.7320 $$

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you go one step to the right, how many steps are you going upwards? That is the slope. Well you know that tan(30) = o/a.  With o the height, aka how many steps you go upwards, and a is basically how many steps you go to the right, which we could take to be one. So the slope is simply tan(30 degrees), and of the other one tan(60 degrees).